# What is the definition of $I(Z)$ when $Z \subseteq Proj S$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes

Let $S$ be a graded ring. In the notes of Ravi Vakil,
he only says "define $I(Z) \subseteq S_+$", when $Z \subseteq Proj S$, where
$S_+$ is all the elements in $S$ that are sum of positive degree homogenous elements in $S$.

He doesn't give the exact definition. Could someone please tell me 
how $I(Z)$ is defined? Thanks!

Comment: Probably something like $S_+ \cap \bigcap_{\mathfrak{p} \in Z} \mathfrak{p}$, no?

Comment: That was my guess, but I just wanted to verify as I wasn't too sure...